# How to set properties in java label

Tags: java

I need to create a Class CustApp that:

- Creates a Customer object, a Customer variable named c, and assigns
  the object to c.
- Set values for Customer properties.
- Creates a CustFrame object and passes the Customer variable c.
- Creates a CustFrame variable named cf, assigns the CustFrame object
  to cf.

So far I have this code, but I can't figure out how to define the properties.

```
public class CustApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setBounds(62, 65, 176, 23);
        c.setBounds(62, 120, 176, 23);
        c.setBounds(62, 175, 176, 23);
        c.setBounds(62, 230, 176, 23);
        c.setText(c.getCustName());
        c.setText(c.getShipToStreet());
        c.setText(c.getShipToCity() + ", " + c.getShipToState() + "    " + c.getShipToZip());
        c.setText(c.getContactPerson() + "    Ph: " + c.getContactPhone());
        CustFrame cf = new CustFrame(c);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think that `Customer` should have `bounds` property.. you never set properties to customer.

Comment: Why on Earth is the code setting a bounds for the `c` object even once, let alone ***4 times***?!?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).